# MySQL JOIN Keeps Timing Out

Tags: mysql, join

I am currently trying to run a JOIN between two tables in a local MySQL database and it's not working. Below is the query, I am even limiting the query to 10 rows just to run a test. After running this query for 15-20 minutes, it tells me "Error Code" 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query". My computer is not going to sleep, and I'm not doing anything to interrupt the connection.

```
SELECT rd_allid.CreateDate, rd_allid.SrceId, adobe.Date, adobe.Id
FROM rd_allid JOIN adobe
ON rd_allid.SrceId = adobe.Id
LIMIT 10
```

The rd_allid table has 17 million rows of data and the adobe table has 10 million. I know this is a lot, but I have a strong computer. My processor is an i7 6700 3.4GHz and I have 32GB of ram. I'm also running this on a solid state drive.

Any ideas why I cannot run this query?

Comment: have you  proper index  on rd_allid.SrceId    and adobe.Id ?

Answer (score 1):

"Why I cannot run this query?"

There's not enough information to determine definitively what is happening. We can only make guesses and speculations. And offer some suggestions.

I suspect MySQL is attempting to materialize the entire resultset before the LIMIT 10 clause is applied. For this query, there's no optimization for the LIMIT clause.

And we might guess that there is not a suitable index for the JOIN operation, which is causing MySQL to perform a nested loops join.

We also suspect that MySQL is encountering some resource limitation which is causing the session to be terminated. Possibly filling up all space in /tmp (that usually throws an error, something like "invalid/corrupted myisam table '#tmpNNN'", something of that ilk. Or it could be some other resource constraint. Without doing an analysis, we're just guessing.

It's possible MySQL wrote something to the error log (hostname.err). I'd check there.

---

But whatever condition MySQL is running into (the answer to the question "Why I cannot run this query")

I'm seriously questioning the purpose of the query. Why is that query being run? Why is returning that particular resultset important?

There are several possible queries we could execute. Some of those will run a long time, and some will be much more performant.

One of the best ways to investigate query performance is to use MySQL `EXPLAIN`. That will show us the query execution plan, revealing the operations that MySQL will perform, and in what order, and indexes will be used.

We can make some suggestions as to some possible indexes to add, based on the query shown e.g.  `on adobe (id, date)`.

And we can make some suggestions about modifications to the query (e.g. adding a WHERE clause, using a LEFT JOIN, incorporate inline views, etc. But we don't have enough of a specification to recommend a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT rd_allidT.CreateDate, rd_allidT.SrceId, adobe.Date, adobe.Id 
FROM 
(SELECT CreateDate, SrceId FROM rd_allid ORDER BY SrceId LIMIT 1000) rd_allidT     
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Id FROM adobe ORDER BY Id LIMIT 1000) adobeT ON adobeT.id = rd_allidT.SrceId;
```

This may help you get a faster response times.

Also if you are not interested in all the relation you can also put some WHERE clauses that will be executed before the INNER JOIN making the query faster also.